# how to prove 2+2+a=4+a in lean4?

Tags: lean4, beginner, equality

It should be simple but dig it for a while and still not successful.
theorem example (a : R) : 2 + 2 + a = 4 + a := ...

can someone help to figure out how to do next? many thanks

Comment: I recommend learning a bit about MWEs.  There is a good website on [MWEs in Lean](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mwe.html).  In particular, use triple backquotes for code and provide all imports (say for the real numbers in your example).

Comment: thanks. that is fine

Answer (score 1):

[`norm_num`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#norm_num) is a good tactic for this sort of stuff:

```
import Mathlib.Tactic.NormNum
import Mathlib.Data.Real.Basic

example (a : ℝ) : 2 + 2 + a = 4 + a := by norm_num
```

(I couldn't find the tactic documentation for Lean 4, so I gave you the documentation for `norm_num` in Lean 3.). But in short, `norm_num` normalizes both sides of this equation.  It works in many places that `rfl` can't work.

Comment: thanks. it works.

Comment: What does norm_num do?

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay I believe it uses various rewrite rules to simplify the expression efficiently.  In particular, I think it uses binary to represent integers (even integer real numbers like in this example).  I know it’s also extensible and you can mark lemmas to be used in norm_num.  This allows you to use norm_num on custom functions or even custom types.  I think for more details it’s best to ask a question here or on the lean Zulip, since I don’t know.